# Remove Element from Set

Tags: java, string, foreach, set, string-length

I'm trying to remove all Strings that are of even length in a set. Here is my code so far, but I am having trouble getting the index from the iterator in the enhanced-for-loop.

```
public static void removeEvenLength(Set<String> list) {
    for (String s : list) {
        if (s.length() % 2 == 0) {
            list.remove(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `getting the index`: there are none, as a Set is not ordered.

Comment: as a side note, your `Set` is named `list`, which is confusing, given that `List` is the name of another `Collection`, but an ordered one (which has indexes.)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A `Set` has no concept of an index of an element. The elements have no order in the set. Moreover, you should use an `Iterator` when iterating to avoid a [`ConcurrentModificationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) when removing an element from a collection *while* looping over it:

```
for (Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    String s =  iterator.next();
    if (s.length() % 2 == 0) {
        iterator.remove();
    }       
}
```

Note the call to `Iterator.remove()` instead of `Set.remove()`.

Comment: any argument in favor of the `for` loop instead of the `while` loop here?

Comment: Not really, I just used a `for` since the OP is already using one. A `while` loop would work but you would make the scope of the `Iterator` outside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 19):

Java 8 has introduced [Collection.removeIf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-), which allows you to do:

```
set.removeIf(s -> s.length() % 2 == 0)
```

Comment: I want to point out that it is `->`, not `=>`. And, it is just a syntax sugar of "iterating and remove with iterator", according to the JavaDoc.

Comment: @WesternGun nice catch, been doing too much TS lately. Yes, the implementation is almost the same as some of the answers above, as can be seen [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Collection.java#l409). You just write less code.

Comment: very sexy solution :)

Answer (score 8):

Just thought that I'd post a Java 8 solution that may help someone in the future. Java 8 Streams offers a bunch of nice methods such as `filter` and `collect`. The `filter` method simply filters out the elements from the stream that should be carried on to the next step. The `collect` method combines elements to a `Collection` of some sort or a `Map`.

```
// The data to filter
final Set<String> strings = 
        new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("a", "ab", "abc", "abcd"));

// Now, stream it!
final Set<String> odds =
        strings.stream()
               .filter(s -> s.length() % 2 != 0) // keep the odds
               .collect(Collectors.toSet());     // collect to a new set
```

This does not actually modify the original collection but creates a new `Set` containing the `String` objects of odd length.

For more reading on Java 8 Streams, checkout this [excellent tutorial from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html) or the [great JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html).

Comment: Good choice when we need to modify the Many side of a `@OneToMany` relationship, deleting a child; need to create a new `Set` and set to the One side.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the index.  But you do need the explicit `Iterator`.  The iterator has the [`remove()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--), no parameters, that removes the current item from the collection.

```
Iterator<String> itr = list.iterator();  // list is a Set<String>!
while (itr.hasNext())
{
    String s = itr.next();
    if (s.length() % 2 == 0) {
        itr.remove();
    }
}
```